# Could not resolve com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, in-app-billing

i started a brand new Project in Android Studio to try to add the billing library. but when i add the dependency `implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'` and sync gradle i get this errors:

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>   Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>   Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>   Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>   Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1.
>   Open File
>   Show Details

here is my gradle:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Tefz.png)

Comment: Could you post the contents of your Gradle file as code instead of a picture? That way we can see your question/problem description and Gradle at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

Modify your **project(not module)** build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" } //add this line
    }
}
```

and **Sync project with Gradle files** again.

Comment: Works for me. I'm new in Android: Why does it work? Where do you get this information? Gradle Errors are very painful to solve.

Answer (score -1):

ok i have resolved it. i added this line `maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }` in my  build.gradle (project) like this:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

Comment: almost post answer at the same time ^_^

Comment: right :) 
i already tried to add the maven url in allprojects{} but it didn't work. in buildscript{} it worked.

thank you for your help anyway.